# PHPSESSID same attribution possible?

Tags: php, random

Is it possible for a webserver to assign a PHPSESSID currently used by another client at the moment of attribution?

Or a check is made before attribution ?

Comment: I am little confused by your question. Are you asking if its possible for PHP to assign the same PHPSESSID to multiple clients?

Comment: Most likely this is possible - During a quick look at the code at github I didn't notice any checks to prevent this. However the session id is pretty long which means the odds of this happening are very very small.

Answer (score 0):

This ID is generated automatically when you make a session_start.

```
 session_start();
```

If you know some ID you can force to assign that to another instance/client, but in my opinion that could be a security risk, I don't recommend you to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Follow logic should work theoretically:

1. Close and save current

   session_write_close();
2. Set new session ID

   session_id(YOUR_SESSION_ID_HERE);
3. Run new session

   session_start();